# How to proceed checkout method login to billing information?

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout

I have some issues in checkout page on magento. When i add products to cart and proceed to checkout, In checkout method when i login to checkout its not proceeding to billing information or shipping information on same page. Instead of its redirecting to login page from there its redirecting to mydashboard page. If i want to checkout, again i need to click cart page and proceed to checkout. I would like clear this issue any ideas ?

Comment: Please provide the code for the checkout you are using

Answer (score 1):

In the configuration area in the admin section there is a setting that will redirect the users to the My Account page after successful login.

You can find these settings under `System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Login Options`. I think you need to set this option to No and then it should redirect the user back to the original page after login.